# Android. How to get mobile internet(data network) turned on/off state?

Tags: android, networking, mobile

I am trying to create button like this (If mobile network is turned on it is green, when it is off, it is grey):

[image]

I am trying to identify state using this method:

```
public Boolean isDataNetworkEnabled() {

    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It always returning value 'false'. Even if after mobile network turned on. Actually, how to identify state of mobile network?

PS. I am not asking about how to turn on/off mobile network, I am asking about state. I have already found how to turn on/off:

```
try {
                    Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
                    if (!isDataNetworkEnabled()) {
                        dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, true);
                        ivDataNetwork.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_data_usage_black_48dp);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Data network turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        dataMtd.invoke(dataManager, false);
                        ivDataNetwork.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_data_usage_grey600_48dp);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Data network turned off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Make sure you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> in your manifest.

Comment: @Ashton, I have these permissions:    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use broadcast receiver

Register reciever under  in manifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.broadcastreciever2.NetworkChangeReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Define your reciever ( Use according to your use )

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NetworkChangeReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (checkInternet(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
        if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Define ServiceManager by extending ContextWrapper

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ServiceManager extends ContextWrapper {

public ServiceManager(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Comment: which method I should use to identify state: isNetworkAvailable from service or checkInternet from receiver? is this only for mobile network ? because i dont want to combine or confuse with wifi

Comment: IsNetworkAvailable don't listen for network availability. You need to listen when network is available. I recommend to use above method.

Comment: Specifically, using `.isConnectedOrConnecting();` means you will have to poll (set up a timer, continue to call this method to determine if network is available) the network connection: using a broadcast receiver means your app will automatically get updated when the network state changes--which is what you want to keep the button state accurate. The type of network is just determined from the arguments you pass to the connection manager.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing some values...

```
 if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( conMgr.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
            || conMgr.getNetworkInfo(TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
        return false;
    }
```

So you are really checking if mobile data is connected, or wifi is connecting. It sounds like you don't want wifi, so change `TYPE_WIFI` to `TYPE_MOBILE`?

In fact it might be slightly better to do:

```
public boolean isMobileDataNetworkAccessable() {
  return conMgr.getNetworkInfo(NetworkType.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Comment: wifi toggle button is working correctly, now i am working with mobile network